# How to get remote computer last input (idle) time

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, batch-file

I have a large number of computer on which periodically I need to perform different actions from time to time (manual updates, cleanups, setups etc...). These clients are in use most of the time but not always.

I'm looking for a way to find out which clients are **inactive** and how long they are inactive for (no user input from mouse/keyboard/barcode scanner).

All the stuff I could find either don't work or work only for local PC/Remote Desktop connections.

Couple of roadblocks regarding my environment:

- `quser/qwinsta` either dont work or show `none` in the `last input` field.
- powershell remoting is disabled
- I would like to avoid using familiar task scheduler "hack" (*create local task/start it remotely/collect result/ delete task*) if at all possible.

I have tried to find a way to do this for 3 or 4 times now, and this is my last resort before I label this task as "impossible" an move on.

Any input or a idea for a different approach is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Best bet is to download software if you're not willing to budge with enabling psremoting

Comment: I am willing, but company isn't and guess who's decision will be final :)
Downloading software isn't an option either for the same reason...

Comment: Does wmi work for you?

Comment: Yes, it does. Is there a way to get this info through wmi?